# Some problems when trying to reproduce the threshold result of simulation of surface code

Tags: surface-code, minimum-weight-perfect-matching

Recently I am trying to do some simulations on the surface code to get the empirical curve of logical error(P_L) corresponding with physical error rate(p) and code distance(d) as [Towards practical classical processing for the surface code](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5133v2) do. However, after several rounds of simulation, I found something weird happened in my work. I can't get the result of threshold theorem do! No matter how low the physical error rate is, adding more qubits always introduce more errors.

So I want to know which part of my simulation is wrong.

The following is my simulation route. Let's take d=5 as example.

Step1: First in my program, I will generate a 5*5 lattice of physical qubits. And in each round of stabilizer measurement simulation, I randomly put errors using the standard Depolarizing noise model on each qubits in the lattice, which means every qubits in the lattice will store an information of one of ['I', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'] with the probability [1 - 8p, 8p/3, 8p/3, 8p/3].

Step2: In this step, I perform stabilizer measurement on the measure qubit to get the "-1" syndrome outcome.(Suppose the measure qubit is to measure the "Z" type stabilizer, then one neighbouring physical qubits containing "X" or "Y" will flip the outcome.) Now, I just consider the perfect measurement case to simpilify the simulation. As a consequence, I just need to do one round of stabilizer measurement, and ignore the time boundary.

Step3: Once I get all of the "-1" syndrome in the stabilizer measurement step, I just perform MWPM algorithm using the library of "networkX". And the distance of two stabilizer is defined as the Manhattan distance.

Step4: With all "-1" pairs as the outcome of MWPM, I generate the operators of the qubits in the shortest path of these pairs. And applying these operators is the error correction step.

Step5: After recovering the error. I combined the simulated error in step1 and the recovery operator in step4 to detect if this round of simulation occurs a logical error. If it does, count it. Return to step1.

The simulation result of my work is:

[image]

---

I possiblly find out where the problem is. Seems like there are some weird results in the usage of the `nx.min_weigh_matching` [min_weight_matching implemented by the networkX lib](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.min_weight_matching.html#networkx.algorithms.matching.min_weight_matching).

Here is the proof. The code is running in the python.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
edges = [(0, 1, {'weight': 3}), (1, 2, {'weight': 1}), (0, 3, {'weight': 1}), (2, 3, {'weight': 0})]
G.add_edges_from(edges)
print(nx.min_weight_matching(G))
```

I generate a complete graph of 4 nodes with the above weight. However, the result is:

```
{(0, 1), (2, 3)}
```

And the total weight(3) of this matching is larger than the total weight(2) of matching {(0, 3), (1, 2)}.

Comment: In step 1, why do you probabilities add up to more than 1?

Comment: I am sorry about that, I have made some mistakes when writting this question. Actually is [1-8p, 8p/3, 8p/3, 8p/3] in my program.

Comment: It is really difficult to identify problem without looking at the code. But the first check you should do is apply a deterministic error at exactly one location and check if your error detection and decoding are working correctly.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Actually, I have already done some checks of my simulation step by step by a simple visualiztion of the checkboard of the surface code. Seems like everything is in the right road. But I have to say is hard to find out all of the protential bugs in the simulation. Suppose there is no bug in my simulation program, I would like to ask if I understand the whole simulation process. Or some technique to improve the threshold value is necessary? Such as the effect of corelated Y-error or the definition of the distance between two stabilizer flip node.